# Understanding TSQL Coalesce function

Tags: t-sql, coalesce

I am trying to select all 12 months / year.  And I thought following TSQL code would do this.  However, this does not include all months like I want.  What is the cause of this?  This is modified code:

```
DECLARE @END_YEAR VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @END_MONTH VARCHAR(10)

SET @END_YEAR = '2010'
SET @END_MONTH = '10'

DECLARE @TheMonthLastDate DATETIME
DECLARE @TempDate DATETIME
SET @TempDate = '2010-11-01 00:00:00.000'
SET @TheMonthLastDate = '2010-11-01 00:00:00.000'

;with months
as  
(
select dateadd(month, -1, dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, @TempDate), 0)) as m
union all
select dateadd(month, -1, m)
from months
where   m > dateadd(month, -12, @TempDate)
)
,yourTable(DateOpened, DateClosed)
as
(select TSK_START_DATE, BTK_CLOSED_DATE
FROM [PROC].ALL_AUDIT
WHERE 
(BTK_CLOSED_DATE < @TheMonthLastDate OR
TSK_START_DATE < @TheMonthLastDate 
)
)
select      yt.DateClosed 'r2', m.m 'r3',
        month(coalesce(yt.DateClosed, m.m)) as 'MonthClosed',
        year(coalesce(yt.DateClosed, m.m)) as 'YearClosed'
from    months m
left join yourTable yt
    on      
    (  datepart(year, yt.DateClosed) = DATEPART(year, m.m)
    and datepart(month, yt.DateClosed) = DATEPART(month, m.m) 
    or    
      datepart(year, yt.DateOpened) = DATEPART(year, m.m)
    and datepart(month, yt.DateOpened) = DATEPART(month, m.m) 
    )
AND year(coalesce(yt.DateClosed, m.m)) = 2010
order by yt.DateClosed
```

So above query does not return all months.  But if I change above WHERE lines to:

```
FROM [PROC].ALL_AUDIT
    WHERE
BTK_CLOSED_DATE < @TheMonthLastDate
```

then this query does return all 12 months.  How can this be?

Output that I want and that I see when WHERE is BTK_CLOSED_DATE < @TheMonthLastDate:

```
r2  r3  MonthClosed YearClosed
NULL    2010-06-01 00:00:00.000 6   2010
NULL    2009-11-01 00:00:00.000 11  2009
2010-01-06 20:02:19.127 2010-01-01 00:00:00.000 1   2010
2010-01-27 23:13:45.570 2010-01-01 00:00:00.000 1   2010
2010-02-15 14:49:14.427 2010-02-01 00:00:00.000 2   2010
2010-02-15 14:49:14.427 2009-12-01 00:00:00.000 2   2010
```

But if I instead use WHERE:
(BTK_CLOSED_DATE < @TheMonthLastDate OR
    TSK_START_DATE < @TheMonthLastDate 
    )

then I see:

```
r2  r3  MonthClosed YearClosed
NULL    2010-10-01 00:00:00.000 10  2010
NULL    2010-09-01 00:00:00.000 9   2010
NULL    2010-09-01 00:00:00.000 9   2010
NULL    2010-08-01 00:00:00.000 8   2010
NULL    2010-08-01 00:00:00.000 8   2010
...
```

So notice that in first result I see NULL for June 2010, which is what I want.
I think the problem has something to do with the fact that my data contains 2009-2011 data, but I only compare months and not years.  How would I add in this additional logic?

Comment: Don't have time to read all the code at the moment, but to answer your title's question, coalesce is essentially an ISNULL with multiple parameters in which it returns the first non-null parameter.

Comment: Does the select statement within the yourTable CTE return the same exact data when you use the OR or not?

Comment: Derek, no it does not.  Not using OR returns 102 records.  Using OR returns 134 records.  Part of problem is I don't understand exactly how CTE works.

Comment: OK, think of a CTE as a view, because thats exactly what it is. The only difference is that it's not stored in the database, a CTE is only used for that one query. So it's a 1-time view. I will say that it doesn't make sense that adding the OR results in no records returned, but it's incredibly difficult to follow your code. if you can somehow post a trimmed down version that exhibits the same pattern that we can investigate, it'll be much easier to help with.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, Derek.  I just reposted simpler code now.  Can you look at this please?

Comment: Just to expand slightly on @Derek Kromm's excellent comments, coalesce is part of the ansi standard where isnull is proprietary. But like he said coalesce is functionally an isnull that accepts multiple paramaters.

Answer (score 2):

The only place where you are reducing the data is with the WHERE clause you have already identified.  Therefore, the reason you are not getting all the months you expect is down to the column TSK_START_DATE not being less than @TheMonthLastDate for all months.

To prove this hypothesis, run the following section of your query (I have commented out part of the where clause and removed everything under 'yourTable' cte).  The results should show you what is being returned in the TSK_Start_Date column for your missing months and help you identify why the rows are missing when applying the < @TheMonthLastDate clause.

```
DECLARE @END_YEAR VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @END_MONTH VARCHAR(10)

SET @END_YEAR = '2010'
SET @END_MONTH = '10'

DECLARE @TheMonthLastDate DATETIME
DECLARE @TempDate DATETIME
SET @TempDate = '2010-11-01 00:00:00.000'
SET @TheMonthLastDate = '2010-11-01 00:00:00.000'

;with months
as  
(
select dateadd(month, -1, dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, @TempDate), 0)) as m
union all
select dateadd(month, -1, m)
from months
where   m > dateadd(month, -12, @TempDate)
)

,yourTable(DateOpened, DateClosed)
as
(select TSK_START_DATE, BTK_CLOSED_DATE
FROM [PROC].ALL_AUDIT
WHERE 
(BTK_CLOSED_DATE < @TheMonthLastDate OR
--TSK_START_DATE < @TheMonthLastDate 
)
)
select * , @TheMonthLastDate TheMonthLastDate from yourTable
```